# Get the value from table indexed by strings

Tags: indexing, lua, lua-table

I have the LUA table:

```
flys = {
["Moltres"] = {229, 2300}, -- moltres
["Articuno"] = {230, 2100}, -- artic
["Zapdos"] = {224, 2600}, -- zapdos
["Mew"] = {232, 2200}, -- 1000
["Mewtwo"] = {233, 2200},-- two
["Dragonite"] = {221, 1300},-- nite
["Pidgeot"] = {222, 900}, -- geot
["Fearow"] = {226, 800}, -- fearow
["Aerodactyl"] = {227, 1100}, -- aero
["Charizard"] = {216, 1000}, -- chari
["Porygon"] = {316, 600}, -- porygon
["Shiny Dragonite"] = {1020, 1300},-- Shiny nite
["Shiny Pidgeot"] = {996, 900}, -- Shiny geot
["Shiny Fearow"] = {997, 800}, -- Shiny fearow          --alterado v2.5
["Shiny Charizard"] = {295, 1000}, -- Shiny chari
["Porygon2"] = {648, 890}, -- 2
["Skarmory"] = {649, 1000}, -- skarmory
["Crobat"] = {652, 1190}, -- crobat

["Dragonair"] = {1112, 1150},
["Shiny Dragonair"] = {1113, 1400},  --alterado v2.5
["Noctowl"] = {994, 1000},
}
```

It's indexed by strings, every element contains 2 numbers.

I can't get the values. I want for example print the number from some table object.

The most obvious way (for me) doesnt work:

```
local pokemon3 = flys["Pidgeot"]
print("pokemon id: "..pokemon3[1])
```

It says its nil value. I tried a lot of combinations of those and none work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't see any issue with the script and it works just fine for me (tested in Lua 5.1, 5.2, and 5.3).

The way you showed is the correct way to do this and if you still have an issue, you need to post the *exact* script that doesn't work for you and the details of the environment you are trying to run it in.

Comment: Yes, you are right it works. I found another table with that name in files I am working on. It was causing the trouble. Thanks